# Updatepanel for LinkButton Not Working Well in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

i have a task for Adding control for linkbutton click.
   for this i i have created 5 Uploadcontrols with existing 5 controls by giving visible false.
here i am doing for every click one control is showing from server side.
 When i click liknbutton everytime postingback..so to restrict this i have added Updatepanel to link button as given below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uploadaddmorepic" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkaddmorepics" runat="server" Text="Add More Pics" 
                                                            onclick="lnkaddmorepics_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkaddmorepics" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>     

in link button click 

  protected void lnkaddmorepics_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        int rowCount = 0;

        //initialize a session.
        rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);

        rowCount++;

        //In each button clic save the numbers into the session.
        Session["clicks"] = rowCount;


        //Create the textboxes and labels each time the button is clicked.
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {

            if (i == 0)
            {
                lblupload6.Visible = true;
                FileUpload5.Visible = true;
                ddlimage5title.Visible = true;
                lblforupload6.Visible = true;
            }

                if (i == 1)
                {
                    lblforuplaod7.Visible = true;
                    lblforupload6.Visible = true;
                    ddlimage6title.Visible = true;
                    FileUpload6.Visible = true;
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    lblforuplaod8.Visible = true;
                    lblforuplaod7.Visible = true;
                    ddlimage7title.Visible = true;
                    FileUpload7.Visible = true;
                }

                if (i == 3)
                {
                    lblforuplaod9.Visible = true;
                    lblforuplaod8.Visible = true;
                    ddlimage8title.Visible = true;
                    FileUpload8.Visible = true;
                }
                if (i == 4)
                {
                    lblforuplaod10.Visible = true;
                    lblforuplaod9.Visible = true;
                    ddlimage9title.Visible = true;
                    FileUpload9.Visible = true;
                }
}
```

getting firing but controls are not showing for every click..plz help me out

Comment: Please provide a more complete code example. For all I know, the controls you are setting to visible=true, might be outside the content template.

Comment: yes..i am setting visible false for controls out side of content template..@ Nick neibling

Comment: yes i did it..i placed the controls inside content template..now it not posting back..but the problem is fileupload control is not holding the file..it is clearing..what should i do for this?? @  Nick Niebling

Comment: It's very difficult to help without an updated code example. Sounds like you are either not trigger correctly? Or maybe you have the FileUpload control inside the ContentTemplate and it doesn't hold it's state between AJAX post backs (this can be tricky to achieve for FileUpload between regular or AJAX post backs).